# double stars in pointer definition

Tags: c, embedded, firmware

I have a come across following definition in an embedded code:

```
#define REG_ADD 0x20081004
#define pREG ((void * volatile *)REG_ADD)
```

Why there are 2 `*` in `pREG` definition? What does it mean?

Comment: Pointer to pointer.

Comment: This is corrrect syntax, but it still looks like a bad idea. Can you provide context?

Comment: @dandi-kain: do a printf() on REG_ADD and it's address, then printf() pREG, DE-refferenced pREG and the address of pREG, this should help you see what is going on...

Comment: You can't "printf" the address of a constant (REG_ADD) since it is not defined. Same goes for pREG. The address of pREG is not defined.

Comment: Cast to [pointer to volatile pointer to void](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+*+volatile+*REG_ADD)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`void**` is a pointer to pointer-to-void.

`void * volatile *` is a pointer to volatile-qualified-pointer-to-void. (Read the declaration right-to-left, pretty much. [See this](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).)

What this means in plain English is that `pREG` is likely a pointer to some sort of hardware index register, which in turn contains an address. To tell the compiler that this index register can get updated at any moment, the register itself should be treated as `volatile`.

A somewhat more readable way to write the same would be:

```
typedef void* volatile reg_add_t;
reg_add_t* pREG = (reg_add_t)0x20081004u;
```

---

Please note that the use of `void*` for this purpose is questionable. This register will have a defined use, possibly it should have been a `uint32_t * volatile` or `uint8_t * volatile` instead.